# What is the difference between .pub-cache directory inside flutter sdk and .pub-cache directory in home?

Tags: flutter, dart, pub.dev

Question is simple. we have 2 .pub-cache directories one inside the flutter sdk folder and one in our home directory eg:

`/home/path/to/flutter/.pub-cache/`

`/home/.pub-cache/`

what is the difference between these two?

Comment: dart pub add  package  add to ::   /home/.pub-cache/

Comment: When looking for the Package cache, it seems to give priority to looking for the cache in the Flutter directory. If not found, it will check from the Dart cache directory.  see  [this](https://www.jianshu.com/p/e1bf053ebab2)